# Preventing Child from firing parent's click event

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

Consider the following snippet:

```
<div class="div-outer">
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.
    <div class="div-inner" style="background:red">
        Curabitur hendrerit vehicula erat, ut gravida orci luctus vitae.
    </div>
</div>
```

Now suppose the outer div has a live `click` associated with it. How do I make sure that the live `click` is not triggered when I `click` anywhere in the inner `div`?

Edit:

Here's the JS as requested

```
$(".div-outer").live("click",function(){alert("hi")});
```

This should not be triggereed when clicking on ".inner-div"

Comment: post your js.jquery code as well.

Answer (score 45, accepted):

You have to add an event listener to the inner child and cancel the propagation of the event.

In plain JS something like

```
document.getElementById('inner').addEventListener('click',function (event){
   event.stopPropagation();
});
```

is sufficient. Note that [jQuery provides the same facility](http://api.jquery.com/event.stopPropagation/):

```
$(".inner-div").click(function(event){
    event.stopPropagation();
});
```

or

```
$(".inner-inner").on('click',function(event){
    event.stopPropagation();
});
```

Answer (score 12):

An alternative solution is to add a **[CSS Pointer Events](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/pointer-events)** rule to the child element:

**CSS:**

```
#childElement {
    pointer-events: none;
}
```

**JavaScript:**

`document.getElementById("childElement").style.pointerEvents = "none";`

Comment: Considering the support for this now, it should likely be the preferred solution. https://caniuse.com/#feat=pointer-events

Answer (score 1):

you can do this by add a click event on the inner div and use either `return false;` or `event.stopPropagation();`

```
$(".div-inner").click(function(){

  return false;
})
```

or

```
$(".div-inner").click(function(event){

  event.stopPropagation();
})
```

<sub><sub><sub>[image: jsFiddle]</sub></sub></sub>

Answer (score 1):

Create new `click` listener for the inner div and call the `event.stopPropagation()` in that new event.

like

```
$('div-outer').on('click','div-inner',function(e){
    e.stopPropagation();
});
```

Comment: What I particularly like about this solution is that it helped me configure the reverse event: when I want the child's event to fire, but not the parent's.

Answer (score 0):

use stopPropagation in your js file

```
 $(".eventclick").click(function(e) {
    e.stopPropagation();
});
```