# Mouseover and mouseout for multiple element

Tags: javascript, html, css

Using Javascript, I have multiple element and when I hover that element, it changes the content and element.

I tried using mouseover and mouseout, it's working for single element, but doesn't work when I have multiple element.

I add loops for the parent, but still not working, also now when I hover the first element, it's just looping over.

What am I doing wrong?

```js
const wrapper = document.querySelectorAll(".wrapper");

wrapper.forEach(function () {
    let mouseWhite = document.querySelector(".commercial-white");
    let mouseBlue = document.querySelector(".commercial-blue");

    mouseWhite.addEventListener("mouseover", function (e) {
        mouseBlue.classList.add("open");
        e.stopPropagation();
    })

    mouseBlue.addEventListener("mouseout", function (e) {
        mouseBlue.classList.remove("open");
        e.stopPropagation();
    })
})
```

```css
  .wrapper {
        display: flex;
        position: relative;
    }

    .commercial-white {
        background-color: #f1f1f4;
        width: 240px;
        height: 260px;
        text-align: center;
        display: flex;
        flex-direction: column;
        justify-content: center;
        align-items: center;
        border-bottom: 15px solid #005da0;
        margin: 10px;
    }

    .commercial-blue {
        position: absolute;
        background-color: #005da0;
        color: #FFFFFF;
        width: 240px;
        height: 273px;
        text-align: center;
        display: flex;
        flex-direction: column;
        justify-content: center;
        align-items: center;
        margin: 10px;
        border: 2px solid #FFFFFF;
        visibility: hidden;
    }

    .open.commercial-blue {
        visibility: visible;
    }

    .commercial-flip {
        padding: 20px;
    }
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
        <div class="commercial-white">
            <div class="commercial-flip">
                <img style="width:100px" src="http://g-ec2.images-amazon.com/images/G/31/img14/anywhere/amazon-logo-500500._V327001990_.jpg">
                <h1>Your title</h1>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="commercial-blue">
            <div class="commercial-flip">
                <img style="width:100px" src="https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/G/01/gc/designs/livepreview/amazon_dkblue_noto_email_v2016_us-main._CB468775337_.png">
                <h1>Lorem Ipsum</h1>
                <p>lorem ipsum dolor si amet lorem ipsum dolor si amet lorem ipsum dolor si amet</p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="wrapper">
        <div class="commercial-white">
            <div class="commercial-flip">
                <img style="width:100px" src="http://g-ec2.images-amazon.com/images/G/31/img14/anywhere/amazon-logo-500500._V327001990_.jpg">
                <h1>Your title</h1>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="commercial-blue">
            <div class="commercial-flip">
                <img style="width:100px" src="https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/G/01/gc/designs/livepreview/amazon_dkblue_noto_email_v2016_us-main._CB468775337_.png">
                <h1>Lorem Ipsum</h1>
                <p>lorem ipsum dolor si amet lorem ipsum dolor si amet lorem ipsum dolor si amet</p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to 'querySelect' on each wrapper, not the document because in your code `document.querySelector(".commercial-white")` will only give you the [first occurence](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/querySelector) of `.commercial-white` .. and it will do that twice, but it will still be the same occurence... **the first one in the document (twice)**. 
Your querySelectorAll gave you a [NodeList](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/NodeList) of elements `wrapper`.
[forEach](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/NodeList/forEach) will go through each element of your NodeList (*kind of*) like an array. wrapper[0] wrapper[1]...
The argument `aWrapper` is just the name for "The current element being processed in the NodeList".
This way, `aWrapper.querySelector` will only "select" within the current element wrapper in the loop.

```
wrapper.forEach(function (aWrapper) {
    let mouseWhite = aWrapper.querySelector(".commercial-white");
    let mouseBlue = aWrapper.querySelector(".commercial-blue");
```

```js
const wrapper = document.querySelectorAll(".wrapper");

wrapper.forEach(function(aWrapper) {

  let mouseWhite = aWrapper.querySelector(".commercial-white");
  let mouseBlue = aWrapper.querySelector(".commercial-blue");

  mouseWhite.addEventListener("mouseenter", function(e) {
    console.log("e.target.classList mouseWhite :", e.target.classList);
    mouseBlue.classList.toggle("open");
  })

  mouseBlue.addEventListener("mouseout", function(e) {
    console.log("e.target.classList mouseBlue :", e.target.classList);
    mouseBlue.classList.toggle("open");
  })
})
```

```css
.wrapper {
  display: flex;
  position: relative;
}

.commercial-white {
  background-color: #f1f1f4;
  width: 240px;
  height: 260px;
  text-align: center;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  border-bottom: 15px solid #005da0;
  margin: 10px;
}

.commercial-blue {
  position: absolute;
  background-color: #005da0;
  color: #FFFFFF;
  width: 240px;
  height: 273px;
  text-align: center;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  margin: 10px;
  border: 2px solid #FFFFFF;
  visibility: hidden;
}

.open.commercial-blue {
  visibility: visible;
}

.commercial-flip {
  padding: 20px;
  pointer-events: none;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="commercial-white">
    <div class="commercial-flip">
      <img style="width:100px" src="http://g-ec2.images-amazon.com/images/G/31/img14/anywhere/amazon-logo-500500._V327001990_.jpg">
      <h1>Your title</h1>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="commercial-blue">
    <div class="commercial-flip">
      <img style="width:100px" src="https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/G/01/gc/designs/livepreview/amazon_dkblue_noto_email_v2016_us-main._CB468775337_.png">
      <h1>Lorem Ipsum</h1>
      <p>lorem ipsum dolor si amet lorem ipsum dolor si amet lorem ipsum dolor si amet</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="commercial-white">
    <div class="commercial-flip">
      <img style="width:100px" src="http://g-ec2.images-amazon.com/images/G/31/img14/anywhere/amazon-logo-500500._V327001990_.jpg">
      <h1>Your title</h1>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="commercial-blue">
    <div class="commercial-flip">
      <img style="width:100px" src="https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/G/01/gc/designs/livepreview/amazon_dkblue_noto_email_v2016_us-main._CB468775337_.png">
      <h1>Lorem Ipsum</h1>
      <p>lorem ipsum dolor si amet lorem ipsum dolor si amet lorem ipsum dolor si amet</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Edit :

For the buggy display I just added  "[pointer-events](https://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/p/pointer-events/): none;" to `.commercial-flip` and it was enough :

```
.commercial-flip {
  padding: 20px;
  pointer-events: none; }
```

I am fairly new to JS (so I may be wrong), but if I understand correctly, it work because if `.commercial-flip` can receive pointer events then when it's hovered, it's parent is not.
Before this modification, as long as you didn't enter the border of `.commercial-flip` it worked just fine.
So apparently hovering a child isn't the same as hovering it's parent if the child can catch the event, but if it can't it's all good.
*Edit* : [Preventing Child from firing parent's click event](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13682435/preventing-child-from-firing-parents-click-event)

*Note* : I used `classList.toggle` instead of `classList.add` and `classList.remove`, and `mousenter` instead of `mouseover` but it's just a personal preference here ; it gives the exact same result.

Comment: Hi thanks, it's working, however, when I move my mouse within the element, it seems the bug still occur, the element looping over from white to blue and vice versa, any idea to fix this?

Comment: Thanks so much, it's working great, but I'm wondering why it's fixed with the pointer-events: none; ?

Comment: Also in the parameter, you add aWrapper, I'm still not quite sure, what is the different if I use document.querySelector instead? why it's working with parameter, but not working when I use document?

Comment: Did a big edit with my current level of understanding of how things work. If anyone want to correct me please feel free to do so !

Answer (score 0):

You have to query the childs:

```
wrapper.forEach(function (el) { 
    let mouseWhite = el.querySelector(".commercial-white"); 
    let mouseBlue = el.querySelector(".commercial-blue"); 
....
```

Comment: Hi thanks, it's working, however, when I move my mouse within the element, it seems the bug still occur, the element looping over from white to blue and vice versa, any idea to fix this?

Answer (score 0):

You're looping over each one but using the same selector which causes some issues. Just change your loop to the following so there's a reference to each element:

```
wrapper.forEach(function (el) {
    let mouseWhite = el.querySelector(".commercial-white");
    let mouseBlue = el.querySelector(".commercial-blue");

    mouseWhite.addEventListener("mouseover", function (e) {
        mouseBlue.classList.add("open");
        e.stopPropagation();
    })

    mouseBlue.addEventListener("mouseout", function (e) {
        mouseBlue.classList.remove("open");
        e.stopPropagation();
    })
})
```

Comment: Hi thanks, it's working, however, when I move my mouse within the element, it seems the bug still occur, the element looping over from white to blue and vice versa, any idea to fix this?