# One element having two onClick events with opposite useState

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm trying to use a custom dropdown with a `useState` hook. I want to show the list when button is clicked but want to hide when user clicks anywhere outside the button. So, I'm having `onClick` events on parent div and button, but the `onClick` event of parent div triggers even when clicking the button, preventing the button to show the list.
Here is the code:

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
    
export default function App() {
  const [showList, setShowList] = useState(false);
  return (
    <div className="" onClick={() => setShowList(false)}>
      <h1>Welcome Here</h1>
      <buton onClick={() => setShowList(true)}>Click here</buton>
      {showList && (
        <ul>
          <li>1</li>
          <li>2</li>
          <li>3</li>
        </ul>
      )}
    </div>
  );
}
```

And this is the codesandbox example: https://codesandbox.io/s/custom-dropdown-ycq90y?file=/src/App.js:0-426

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to stop the propagation of the event:

```
<button
  onClick={(event) => {
    event.stopPropagation() // <--- this makes the event not bubble up the tree
    setShowList(true)
  }}
>
  Click here
</button>
```

This is not React specific, React is only wrapping the native behaviour for it's synthetic events.

Comment: Which is why there's at *least* one very well-established dupetarget for this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13682435/preventing-child-from-firing-parents-click-event